# Chart.js not working on facebook app

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am implementing a facebook app..i use inside this app Chart.js to show graphs..the problem is while the framework is instanstiated properly when i test the app on web browsers, when i try it on inside facebook i get the following message:

```
"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'"
```

Chart.js initialization:

```
MpM.initializeActions = function() {
    $("<canvas id='mycanv' width='700' height='400' />").appendTo($(".vote-poll-content"));
    MpM.initializeCharts();


MpM.initializeCharts = function() {
    var ctx = $("#mycanv").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var answer_labels = [];
    var answer_percentage = [];

    var data = {labels:[10,23,12,],datasets:[
                                                {
                                                        label           :   "My First dataset",
                                                        fillColor       :   "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                                        strokeColor     :   "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                                                        highlightFill   :   "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                                                        highlightStroke :   "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                                        data            :   [10,23,21,23]
                                                 },
                                              ]
               };

    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, {barValueSpacing : 25});

};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you may just need to set the content security policy to allow scripts from your facebook app url in the http header

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://yourfacebookappurl.com
```

[Content-Security-Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)

Comment: are all of your data requests loading from your facebook app and not external sources? Could be blocked by cross site script protection.

Comment: in the Content-Security-Policy header add the 'unsafe-eval' to the ending... yourfacebook.appurl.com 'unsafe-eval'. but forewarning this would lower the security and allow unsafe javascript to be run. (use as a test to see if it allows your script to run).